# Games and programming... Are these valid topic combinations for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I noticed a question here about [Second Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Life) and checked Stack Overflow for some questions about the [Linden Scripting Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linden_Scripting_Language). There are a few questions about Linden Scripting Language so apparently, it has become reasonable acceptable. The discussion in that question was if Second Life is a videogame or 
not. Well, not important...

I can imagine that there are more games with their own scripting abilities (I don't have a list of them, but if anyone knows one, feel free to share). Scripts could even be an important part of writing [modifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_%28video_gaming%29) for certain games.

Now, is Stack Overflow an appropriate location to ask questions about scripts within games? Or isn't there any place for video-games on Stack Overflow?

(*Remember: the question should focus on scripting/programming possibilities within a game, not the game itself.*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - FWIW, there are also plenty of game programming questions on Stack Overflow in the sense of "I'm writing a game and have encountered *problem X*". That's fine. They're programming questions that also happen to be game-related.

The question that prompted *that other* post here this morning wasn't a programming question. It wasn't really even a computer question, apart from the fact that Second Life runs on computers. It was a Second Life question, pure and simple.

Answer (score 3):

If it's game **programming** it's fine. If it's game **design** then it's a bit grey area with a bias to closing.

Comment: But isn't design also part of development? Developers tend to be more than just code-typing monkeys. Right?

Comment: I thought about that a bit before, and I don't think that design is part of development. There is a reason why Game Designer is a different job than Programmer in many jobs. You can as well say that Graphic Design is part of Development. Strictly by looking at the FAQ, I don't think that Game Design fits on SO, because most game design problems are usually not programming related. There is always a grey area of course.

Comment: +1, good point! Not that I fully agree, but still, good point. While software developing is my main line of work, I do the occasional graphic design to give a first impression to products before a professional designer will take it over. It's just practical that I don't have to wait for him to create something first.

Comment: @Michael Stum: if someone asked a question about accounting software design, no-one would bat an eyelid. It's more a kind of games-are-not-serious prejudice mixed with a I've-heard-this-is-inappropriate-for-SO-so-I'll-jump-on-the-bandwagon-and-people-will-think-I'm-contributing type of thing. It's generally well intentioned but not healthy for the community.

Comment: @MGOwen: It's not the design of the software architecture, it's on a lower level. If I make a question "Should Sales Tax be applied on food if the customer comes from Iceland?", it will get closed as not programming related. Similarly, when I ask "Should a Mage Ice Shield reflect Ice Arrows shot by a Hunter" or "Should Strength increase Attack Power by 1 or by 2", it is also not programming related. This is Game Design. The actual implementation if increasing a stat in code is programming again, but that's past design.

Answer (score 2):

I vote yes, questions about scripting within the Second Life engine should be acceptable. After all, it IS programming and it is a language used by thousands of developers worldwide. Just be careful to keep your questions programming-related, and not venture off into the many avenues of discussion when it comes to Second Life.

I used to play a [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) game that came with its own scripting-engine, centered around a language called COG. I would have loved to have a Stack Overflow-like site in the late 1990s to better understand the syntax and capabilities.

Comment: Do you have a reference for COG?

Comment: Not a very good one: http://www.jkhub.net/library/index.php?title=Reference:COG_Language